# subprocess.call - grep -c doesn't return correct value

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I am trying to use python's subprocess.call to carry out the follwoing unix funciton :

```
grep -c 'Frame:0' file.txt
```

My python code looks like this :

```
frame0Count=int(unix.call("grep -c 'Frame:0' %s"% fileNameVariable,shell=True))
```

There are no occurences found, the screen output is :

```
0
```

However, the *frame0Count* var has the value 1, not 0.

Can anyone explain why this is ?

Thanks

Comment: `subprocess.call`  doesn't return the text output of the command, it returns whether or not the command succeeded. If you want the output of grep, have a look at `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: oh , thanks.  I actually tried check_output previously but I was getting an error when no occurrences were found

Comment: @user1338194 can you not suppress grep's error when no lines are returned by using the `--silent` parameter? This way you could use @SimonFraser 's suggestion of using `check_output`

Comment: I found an answer to my solution based on Simon's suggestion to not use subprocess.call.  I posted as an answer.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

As Simon pointed out my apporach was wrong.  To achieve my goal I can do the following :

```
callStringframe0= unix.Popen('grep -c Frame:0 %s' % fileNameVariable , 
                              stdout=unix.PIPE,
                              stderr=unix.STDOUT, 
                              shell=True)
frame0Count=int(callStringframe0.stdout.read())
```

This gives me the correct answer.